# java bpm for large data and multi-istantiation of sub workflow

Tags: java, database, business-process-management

Can anyone suggest me a opensource java bpm/workflow solution for operating large number of records in the database. These records may be in millions. And every record will create a subworkflow for string operation on them.

We have used bonita open solutions for this. But to no avail as the execution/initiation time it takes is too long. We need a bpm that must be light weight and fast.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Open Source? Commercial?

Comment: You can try Open ESB: http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/

Comment: Thanks for the answer ftom2. Can you please elaborate me how this will be helpful for me in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

jBPM - http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/

> jBPM is a flexible Business Process Management (BPM) Suite. It makes
>   the bridge between business analysts and developers. Traditional BPM
>   engines have a focus that is limited to non-technical people only.
>   jBPM has a dual focus: it offers process management features in a way
>   that both business users and developers like it.

Activiti BPM Platform - http://activiti.org/

> Activiti is a light-weight workflow and Business Process Management
>   (BPM) Platform targeted at business people, developers and system
>   admins. Its core is a super-fast and rock-solid BPMN 2 process engine
>   for Java. It's open-source and distributed under the Apache license.
>   Activiti runs in any Java application, on a server, on a cluster or in
>   the cloud. It integrates perfectly with Spring, it is extremely
>   lightweight and based on simple concepts.